# Imagemosaic configuration GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, image-mosaic, gdaladdo, coverage

I created an imagemosaic store from 1000x1000x1m rasters `Tiled=true, 256x256, avarage 2 4 8 16 32 64`

and set configure.props file inside the folder as

`Levels = 2.0,2.0 4.0,4.0 8.0,8.0 16.0,16.0 32.0,32.0 64.0,64.0`

`LevelNum = 6`

Layer is working as should on the QGIS, but when I zoom on the close levels it renders as a 2m raster (And is also SLOW as hell and drops errors on the serverlog)
On the coverage.xml file for this layer inside the grid tags `<scaleX=-2><scaleY=2>`

After reading around half of internet, and not able to find the answer. I came in the conclusion that it should be `scaleX=--1 scaleY= 1` and to achieve that `Levels=`
should have contained also  `1.0,1.0` for the raster to render a native resolution? (And also correct `LevelNum`?)
If that is the actual cause, is there a way to fix this other way than removing old & creating a new layer/store?

Tutorial was slightly confusing about this, for me atleast

`Levels = "Represents the resolutions for the various levels of the granules of this mosaic."`

Levels = all overviews + native resolution?

`LevelsNum = "Represents the number of reduced resolution layers that we currently have for the granules of this mosaic."`

LevelsNums = How many overviews? How many reduced resolution layer file?